# Change "created by" or alternative

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level

I am trying to develop a time off request system. One list will hold all the employee's and their accrued time off. Naturally I only want 99% of users to only be able to see theirs. I want to limit it by "users can only see what they created" option, however they won't be creating their entry, HR will when their are hired.

I would use a view but there isn't a way to lock it down, so a semi-intelligent person can switch views or just tweak the one that I setup.

What are some options? I have tried to find a way to change the "created by" field but it doesn't seem possible. What work around or options do I have?

This is a basic license modern SharePoint online site.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: item level permissions on list items. break permissions inheritance & assign permissions only to HR and the employee. you can automate this using Power Automate on item creation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Created By` and `Modified By` fields in SharePoint Online via the REST API. Here's an answer from the Microsoft Q&A:

[REST API to create item with custom Created by and Modified by values in Sharepoint online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/221106/rest-api-to-create-item-with-custom-created-by-and.html?childToView=221852#answer-221852)

Answer (score 0):

Here, some solutions to edit the createdBy field and a focus on Power Automate: https://blog.lsonline.fr/2021/02/28/sharepoint-client-side-page-author/

Hoping this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Simple test for your reference:

[image]

Compose:

```
[
  {
    "FieldName": "Author",
"FieldValue":"[{'Key':'i:0#.f|membership|user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com'}]"
  }
]
```